# js accessing blob data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, blob

I try to upload a file to aws s3

upload works. Problem is the data type.

The file I try to upload is a blob like this:

`blob:http://localhost:8080/2957b409-cab8-4564-b696-76c0af6ef64f`

The uploaded file contains only the string above and not the file (image) which is in the blob.

How can I access the blob and upload the original file?

UPDATE:

I found this and us it now:

```
   const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = () => {
    const fileAsBinaryString = reader.result;

    this.awsS3UploadHelper(pictures,fileAsBinaryString);

    // do whatever you want with the file content
};
reader.onabort = () => console.log('file reading was aborted');
reader.onerror = () => console.log('file reading has failed');
reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

`fileAsBinaryString` contains a very long string with stuff ... I think the file content ... when I save the file to aws S3 the whole content is in the file and is stored.

But when I open the file nothing is display in image viewer. when I open the file with editor the same string is in the file ...

What could be the problem?

I think it's an encoding problem could that be?

`fileAsBinaryString`contains stuff like this :

`PNG

`

the original file starts like this
`‰PNG`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is to use:

`reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);`  instead of `reader.readAsBinaryString(file);`